# Generalized eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a huge sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have a huge symmetric sparse matrix and I want to calculate the `k` largest(or smallest) eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors.

The eigenvalue problem is not too hard to solve (Lanczos, QR, etc) and the results are promising. However, calculating their corresponding eigenvectors is a more complicated problem, since all the algorithms require too much memory, as I can't work with a full matrix of the same size of the original one.

Is there an efficient way to calculate the eigenvectors?

Comment: Please define "generalized eigenvalue". If the matrix is symmetric, it should have orthogonal eigenvectors.